# How do I format an external HDD for Ubuntu and Windows7?

Tags: external-hdd

I think that it is supposed to be FAT32, but, Windows7 will not open it. Is there another formatting option?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what you're trying to do?  I'm confused by what you're trying to ask :/

Comment: I am trying to copy files from one computer to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use NTFS, it's a wiser solution for an external disk on most cases. But Windows 7 should be able to read FAT partitions right, usually usb sticks are just formated in FAT. It's quite strange that you are seeing this issue.

Comment: Great! This solved the problem!